# Trouble calling becomeFirstResponder on searchBar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make it so when a user goes to the search page, the keyboard is immediately available. I'm using this code (calling it in viewDidLoad after the block runs which creates the resultSearchController):

```
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: plz edit with ur full code

Answer (score 0):

This is what i'd do in obj-c change it to swift::

```
 UITextField *searchField = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];

[searchField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: he needs swift answer

Comment: As per what i understand the cocoa touch framework behaves similarly regardless of the language being used. My point here is that you don't make the searchbar the first responder but, the UITextfield that is inside the search bar the first responder.